# org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException while using CDI @Named and @Inject

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cdi

I can access the beans just fine when I replace the annotations with their Spring equivalent (@Component and @Autowired), but it won't work with CDI. javax.inject is present as a dependency in the pom.xml file and I see javax.inject-1.jar in my Maven dependencies with 6 annotation definitions, including Named and Inject.
Here's my App file -

```
package tempTestCdiError;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;

@SpringBootApplication
public class CdiTestApp {
    static Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CdiTestApp.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext = SpringApplication.run(CdiTestApp.class, args);
        CdiBiz business = applicationContext.getBean(CdiBiz.class);
        LOGGER.info("{}, dao-{}", business, business.getCdiDao());
    }
}
```

The error shows up because of this line - `CdiBiz business = applicationContext.getBean(CdiBiz.class);`

Edit: Switching from javax.inject to jakarta.inject solves the issue

Comment: applicationContext.getBean() is pure Spring. Only ‘@Component’ (or it’s extensions) will cause a class to be placed in application context, not ‘@Named’. You need to access CdiBiz business with ‘@Inject’. Also javax.inject has moved to jakarta.inject so you should be using a jakarta.inject dependency with 17+

Comment: Was you problem primarily the java 17 jakarta issue or the fact that ‘@Inject’ is not connected with applicationContext?